# How do I check to see if a model has a photo with Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a model - `Post` - that can have images & files uploaded to them. Two different uploaders in Carrierwave.

What I want to do is, do a simple check for the presence of a photo upload on an object and if it is detected I will display the image tag. But if it isn't, then it shows nothing.

I tried this:

```
<% if post.photo %>
    <%= image_tag post.photo, size: "52", :class => 'entry-avatar' %>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work, it always shows this:

```
<img class="entry-avatar" height="52" src width="52">
```

When it isn't blank, it adds the file path, correctly, to the `src` attribute.

If I try to check for `photo.nil?` it doesn't work, even though it seems like it should:

```
 > a 
 => #<Post id: 1, title: "Fire at Bible College in Christian", photo: nil, body: "A massive fire is now raging at the Bible College ...", created_at: "2014-08-28 08:06:19", updated_at: "2014-09-18 23:35:04", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: nil, slug: "fire-at-bible-college-in-christian", publication_status: 1, has_eyewitness: true>
```

Notice that the `:photo` attribute above is set to `nil`...yet when I do this:

```
 > a.photo
 => #<PhotoUploader:0x00000102e19878 @model=#<Post id: 1, title: "Fire at Bible College in Christian", photo: nil, body: "A massive fire is now raging at the Bible College ...", created_at: "2014-08-28 08:06:19", updated_at: "2014-09-18 23:35:04", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status: nil, slug: "fire-at-bible-college-in-christian", publication_status: 1, has_eyewitness: true>, @mounted_as=:photo> 
 > a.photo.nil?
 => false
```

It doesn't work.

Is there a Carrierwave method that I can use to do this or some other way?

Comment: Once check this and see what is the output: `a.photo?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to check `photo` attribute with `nil?` method. You can directly check like `a.photo?` it returns Boolean value based on the whether file is present or not.